# Feather icons usage in Vue.JS

Tags: vue.js, icons, vuejs2, custom-data-attribute

I've been trying to use ***[feather-icons](https://feathericons.com/)*** in a new vue project.
I first initialized the project using the vue-clie tools:

```
vue init webpack
```

once done, I ran:

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

After that I installed feather-icons through npm as follows:

```
npm install --save feather-icons
```

Once done, I tried using the icons by importing the module in my main.js file:

***main.js:***

```
import 'feather-icons'

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: {
    App
  }
})
```

Then I tried using an icon in a Hello component:

***Hello.vue:***

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1> Hello World!</h1>
    <i data-feather="flag"></i>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'hello',
    data() {
      return {
        msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
      }
    }
  }

</script>
<style>
</style>
```

No error is detected during execution, yet the icon set refuses to work. I've tried including the feather-icons directly on the index.html file, but the problem persists.

I'm guessing whatever is causing this is related to the ***data-feather*** attribute on the ***i*** tag required to invoke feather-icons.

I've been at it for almost a couple hours, but nothing I tried seems to work. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

***UPDATE 1:***
As per  @yuriy636's suggestion, I imported feather-icons in my App component then called feather.replace() in mounted:

***App.vue:***

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  import feather from 'feather-icons'

  export default {
    name: 'app',

    mounted() {
      feather.replace();
    }
  }

</script>

<style>
</style>
```

***UPDATE 2:***

As pointed out by @smarx, there is a module named ***[vue-feather-icons](https://github.com/mage3k/vue-feather-icon)*** that facilitates the usage of feather-icons with vue. just install it, import it and use it.
This seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: Try calling `feather.replace()`(well, for that you have to name the feather import) as stated at the docs https://github.com/colebemis/feather#quick-start. You could place that in the `mounted` hook.

Comment: @yuriy636 Thank you very much, your solution worked. I did as you said and imported feather in my App.vue component then invoked the replace method in mounted. I will edit my original post to reflect the changes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: FYI, you may want to use https://github.com/mage3k/vue-feather-icon instead. It seems like that's easier to integrate with Vue than trying to call `feather.replace` at the right times. (I *think* the `mounted` hook won't be sufficient if the component ever updates?)

Comment: (Updates the icon, that is.)

Comment: @smarx Thanks for the suggestion. I was aware of the vue-feathers-icon module but I wanted to figure out what was wrong with my code first before trying it out. I gave it a shot and it's pretty neat. Thanks again.

Comment: For others who might stumble upon this, once you've called `feather.replace`, the original element is gone, so Vue is unable to update it. You can't, e.g., do something like `<i v-bind:data-feather="iconName"></i>` and expect the icon to update. (This applies to just using `feather-icons` directly. `vue-feather-icon` is presumably well integrated with Vue.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Summarizing the comment thread and presenting another solution for posterity:

1. The issue with the original code is that there's a missing call to `feather.replace`, which finds all the elements with `data-feather` attributes and replaces them with the appropriate icon's SVG.
2. Calling `feather.replace` in the `mounted` hook is good enough for simple use cases, but it doesn't allow for icons changing. (In general, it strikes me as a bad idea to let non-Vue code modify the HTML you're using Vue to render.) E.g., `<i v-bind:data-feather="iconName"></i>` isn't going to allow for subsequent updates.
3. [`vue-feather-icon`](https://github.com/mage3k/vue-feather-icon) appears to be a project that integrates better with Vue.

Below is a better way to use "vanilla" `feather-icons` without running into the above issues. Here, we're dynamically updating the HTML content of a `div` with the appropriate icon SVG by using a computed property that calls `feather.toSvg`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <div v-html="iconSvg"></div>
    <button @click="clicky">Click me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import feather from 'feather-icons'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: 'Hello, World!',
      icon: 'flag'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    iconSvg: function () {
      return feather.toSvg(this.icon)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clicky: function () {
      this.message = 'clicked'
      this.icon = 'circle'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I just want to add that `feather.toSvg()` is deprecated, we should use `feather.icons[name].toSvg()` instead

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done as a functional component, and you can use the icon-names to simply pick which svg to render.

You can also swap out feathers and use another svg-sprite

```
// Usage    
    <div class="flex items-center p-2 mt-2 bg-white">
      <x-svg icon="log-out" class="w-4 h-4" />
    </div>

 // x-svg.vue
    <template functional>
      <svg
        fill="none"
        :viewBox="props.viewBox"
        :class="['stroke-' + props.stroke, data.class, data.staticClass]"
        class="inline-flex w-4 h-4 text-gray-500 stroke-current hover:text-gray-900 group-hover:text-gray-900"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        :ref="data.ref"

        :style="[data.style, data.staticStyle]"
        v-bind="data.attrs"
        v-on="listeners"
      >
        <use :href="require('@/assets/img/feather-sptite.svg') + '#' + props.icon" />
      </svg>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      props: {
        icon: {
          type: String,
          default: 'alert-circle'
        },
        stroke: {
          type: Number,
          default: 1,
          validator(v) {
            const sizes = [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5]
            return sizes.includes(v)
          }
        },
        viewBox: {
          type: String,
          default: '0 0 24 24'
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```